# TextView content not wrapping or scrolling

Tags: android

I have a simple TextView that displays some text that I've scraped of the web.  Despite the fact that the text I want to display is much longer than the width of the screen, it neither wraps nor gives me a scroll bar.  It just stops.

My layout is configured as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/displayFighterVerse"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:width="0dip"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="Welcome to Fighter Verses. Please wait while we download the latest verse."
    />
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't displaying properly?  What really simple thing am I missing?

Comment: What's your parent? You should include more of your XML Layout for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

take a Editetext instead..
set background color to transarent
and setEditable false
it will wrap as well as scroll and will look like a textView

Answer (score 0):

Place your TextView inside a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: While still wrapped by a ScollView, try removing the singleLine, width and inputType xml attributes from the TextView. If this also doesn't work try changing the layout_height to fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Place the TextView inside a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView.